# Converting number to date format using Power Query Editor

Tags: numbers

I need help to convert Numbers into date format using Power Query Editor in either Excel or PowerBI
The date appears in number form like this **930101** and I want to convert it to normal Uk date format

Comment: in your sample string, please say the YY mm and dd sequence.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure which one is month and which one is date among "0101" in your string. But you can handle this your self and follow this below steps for get your required output in **Power Query Editor**-

First, split your string value using fixed 2 character and your data will be divide into 3 column now. define which one is Year, Month and Day.

Now, merge those 3 column maintain the UK pattern DD/MM/YY using a separator "/" and you will get a string like "01/01/93".

Finally, create a custom column using the below code-

```
Date.From([Merged],"en-GB")
```

Here is the final output-

[image]

In the above image, you can see the date in still US format just because of my Laptop's locally setup.